# Как организовать пагинацию на MODX?

Tags: modx, pagination

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, когда пытаюсь построить пагинацию.

```
[[pdoResources? 
&limit=`0`
&depth=`1` 
&includeTVs=`imageUsluga` 
&parents=`2` 
&includeContent=`1` 
&tpl=`uslugiTpl` 
&sortby=`publishedon` 
&sortdir=`DESC` ]]
```

Я вывожу ресурсы на страницу (у меня их 8), тут все окей!

Но теперь я хочу, чтобы ресурсы не все выводились, а, например, по 2 штуки и с пагинацией.
Значит, я делаю:

```
    [[pdoPage?
    &tpl=`@INLINE <p>[[+idx]] <a href="/[[+uri]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></p>`
    &limit = `2` ]]
    [[+page.nav]] 
    [[+pageCount]]
```

У меня выводяться ссылки 4 штуки (логично limit = 2, а ресурсов 8 = 4 страницы),
НО эти ссылки ведут `?page=НОМЕР`, но ничего не происходит, ДАЖЕ ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО и при переходе по ссылке я так и вижу все 8 моих ресурсов, как бы пагинация есть на вид, но не отрабатывает, что я делаю не так?

И да, выводит как-то странно...

[image]

Последняя 4 - это `[[+pageCount]]`, а вот первые "Услуга 3"... откуда вылезли...

Заранее благодарен за помошь.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то это странно, я объединил pdoResources и pdoPage - и заработало, как-то странно и неправильно, поломался этот чанк в других местах теперь .... :c

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &limit=`4`
    &tpl=`uslugiTpl`
    &includeTVs=`imageUsluga`
    &includeContent=`1`
]]
<div class='pagination'>[[!+page.nav]]</div>
```

Comment: `getResources (pdoResources)` - НЕ работают с пагинацией

`getPage (pdoPage)` - работают с пагинацией